# reactjs-components@5.0.3 requires a peer of cnvs@1.1.14 but none was installed

Tags: javascript

I would like too install redux package. When i am using "npm install redux" i have warrning like this.

─ UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY cnvs@1.1.18 extraneous 
├── gulp-sass@4.1.0  extraneous
├── gulp-sourcemaps@2.6.5  extraneous
├── gulp-watch-sass@1.4.1  extraneous
├── node-sass@4.14.1 
├── react-gemini-scrollbar@2.3.4  extraneous
├── react-redux@7.2.1 
├── react-transition-group@4.4.1  extraneous
├── reactjs@1.0.0  extraneous
├── reactjs-components@5.0.3  extraneous
├── redux@4.0.5  extraneous
├── sass@1.26.10  extraneous
└── usestate@1.1.3  extraneous

reactjs-components@5.0.3 requires a peer of cnvs@1.1.14 but none was installed.

How too fix it?

Answer (score 0):

there are some solutions

1. `npm install cnvs@1.1.14`
2. `npm audit fix` (this one requires you to have a package.json file [get that by `npm init`])
   tell me if one works
   OR
   list the problems that you face

Answer (score 0):

Now when i am using npm install redux everythink looks fine but, this is my package.json and i dont have 'redux' in dependencies. When i wanna use 
 
import { createStore } from 'redux';
my Webstorm dont see redux package.

{ 
"name": "my-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.13.1",
"react-dom": "^16.13.1",
"react-redux": "^7.2.1",
"react-scripts": "0.9.5"
},
"devDependencies": {
"gulp": "^4.0.2"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App]
(https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).",
"main": "index.js",
"author": "",
"license": "ISC"
}